# Laravel: Error [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying save a register in my `MySQL` database using `Eloquent` of `Laravel 5`

I edited database information in `.env` file, localized in my system root path, and in `config/database.php` maintain `'default' => 'mysql'` and other mysql connection information (it using `env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')` for get informations)

I can use `Migration`, but when I trying save register using function `save()` of my `Model`:

```
$newClient = new Client;
$newClient->name = "John";
$newClient->save();
```

It will occur the fallowing error:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
could not find driver
```

[image]

================================================================
For @user3158900:

I think my `PHP` has `MySQL` extension installed, fallowing my `phpinfo()` about `Mysql`

[image]

```
>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imap
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: It's usually listed under mysqlnd in the API Extensions box.  It looks like you have it on the command line though, are you using WAMP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using WAMP, your webserver and command line are using different php configurations.

Be sure to enable the pdo_mysql extension in both config files or using the WAMP options.

Comment: I am using xampp for linux, i.e lampp  
but still having the same issues, not sure why
--------------
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver

    in Connector.php line 55
    at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=basicfeetdb', 'root', '', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 55
    at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;

any help is appreciated. Thanks