# How to connect to database in my hosting server?

Tags: php, laravel, bluehost

I have uploaded files . My page is displaying fine except that it's not connecting to mysql database and giving below error. I am using bluehost shared hosting service, it previously had php 5.4 but upgraded to 5.6 beta now. I am using Laravel framework 5.1.

```
   PDOException in Connector.php line 50:could not find driver
```

Please help if I am missing something in online project.

Comment: install or enable the pdo_mysql extension

Comment: What's 5.6 beta? The issue appears to be that bluehost doesn't have the db driver you need to connect to the database you've defined.

Comment: A similar question has already been [Laravel: Error [PDOException]: Could not Find Driver in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529583/laravel-error-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough stated you have missing a mysql driver. You can get bluehost technical support to find out what are the driver test was installed and available for you.

You can refer here for some clues : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database